# Invalid character in date/time specification

Tags: shell, unix, awk, scripting, aix

sample code :

```
modified_time=`ls -lt core* | head -1 | awk '{print $6,$7,$8}'`
echo modified time = $modified_time
```

I am trying to convert the last modified time for a file in seconds with the help of below command on aix box

```
t2=`date +'%s' -d "$modified_time"`
echo t2 = $t2
```

Note : the code i have posted is working on cygwin on bash. However its giving error on AIX ( ksh ).
I am getting below error :

```
egdev04{stc}[/home/stc]% t2=`date +'%s' -d "$modified_time"`

Invalid character in date/time specification.
Usage: date [-u] [+Field Descriptors]
```

Could someone please let me know what part of the code is wrong and suggest what needs to be used instead.

Comment: You should not use old and outdated back-tics, use parentheses. First line could also be shorten some: `modified_time=$(ls -lt core* | awk 'NR==1 {print $6,$7,$8}')`

Comment: According to the error message, the wrong part is the `date` command. Please, try `date -d "$modified_time" +'%s'`

Comment: it didnt work. the code i have posted is working on cygwin on bash.
However its giving error on AIX ( ksh ).

Comment: @Ameet Please updated your original post with this important info.

Comment: what is the output of `echo modified time = $modified_time`

Comment: egdev04{stc}[/home/stc]% echo modified time = $modified_time
modified time = Dec 8 17:49

Comment: Did you read the `date` man page?

Comment: Please, read the `date` man page. I guess the AIX `date` command (as in other *NIX) does not know the `-d` option.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `date(1)` is really poorly covered by standards, especially on dated systems, such as AIX (no pun intended).

Even on modern GNU/Linux vs BSD systems, there are different keys to achieve the behavior that you try to invoke:

- GNU date has one key:

  ```
  -d, --date=STRING
          display time described by STRING, not 'now'
  ```
- BSD date would use two keys and special invocation:

  ```
  date [-jnRu] -f input_fmt new_date  [+output_fmt]

  -j       Do not try to set the date.  This allows you to use the -f flag
           in addition to the + option to convert one date format to
           another.
  -f       Use input_fmt as the format string to parse the new_date provided
           rather than using the default [[[[[cc]yy]mm]dd]HH]MM[.ss] format.
           Parsing is done using strptime(3).
  ```

AIX doesn't seem to include either one of these facilities. So, ultimately, if you really need that you'll have to execute a micro-script in some scripting language, such as Perl/Ruby/Python/etc.

Going a step backwards, parsing results of `ls(1)` is always a very bad idea, as they tend to vary wildly based on particular OS implementation, locale, output format, "human-readable" defaults, etc. If you really just want to get some file modification time, why don't you use `stat(1)`? May be it's available on AIX? Something like

```
stat -c '%Y' "$file"
```

seems to solve your task.